# Total price of items in the cart

Tags: django

Hello I have a problem I can not get total price in my template. I have no idea what i did wrong. Even if I set cart.total = 10 in views.py it does not apply. It is just 0.00 or does not display anything.

models.py

```py
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order_item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=CASCADE, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class Cart(models.Model):
    order_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    order_items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, decimal_places=2, max_digits=11)

    @property
    def total_price(self):
        return self.OrderItem_set.aggregate(
            total_price=Sum(F('quantity') * F('item__price'))
        )['total_price'] or Decimal('0')
```

HTML:

```html
{% extends 'shop/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    {% include 'shop/navbar.html' %}
    <div>
        {% for item in cart %}
        <li>User: {{ item.order_user }}<li/>
        <li>Items: 
                {% for order_item in item.order_items.all %}
                    {{ order_item.order_item.title}}
                {% endfor %}
        <li/>
        <li>Is ordered: {{ item.ordered }}<li/>
        <li>Total: {{ item.total }}<li/>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <td class="num">{{ cart.total_price|floatformat:"2" }}</td>

</div>
  
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your template you're not rendering the result of total_price, but item.total.
Which is set to 0.00 by default.

So instead of

```
<li>Total: {{ item.total }}<li/>
```

It should be

```
<li>Total: {{ item.total_price }}<li/>
```